# tinymce 4.3.4 video_template_callback

Tags: javascript, tinymce-4

The goal is to populate "Embed" field in "insert/edit video" dialog with data from my DOM.
As I understood from the [docs](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/media/#video_template_callback) there is "video_template_callback" for this purpose:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '#text',
    theme: 'modern',
    height: 300,
    menubar: false,
    plugins: ['media code'],
    toolbar: 'media code',
    video_template_callback: function (data) {
        console.log('data');
    },
});
```

But the callback does not fire when calling "insert/edit video" dialog. 
May be I mistaken trying to implement this way. Thanks for help.

Comment: I have the same problem with tinymce version 4.5.2, video_template_callback is not being triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had issues with `video_template_callback` in version 4.7.3.
I tried to add `onclick` and `controlslist` props to my video tag. Initially, it didn't appear, but after some time of research I figured out that TinyMCE has a whitelist of tag properties and I need to add it to the extended_valid_elements. It works with this configuration:

```
extended_valid_elements: 'video[onclick|controlslist|controls]',
video_template_callback: ({
  width, height, poster, source1, source1mime, source2, source2mime,
}) => [
   `<video onclick="playFunction" controls controlslist="nodownload"`
   `width="${width}" height="${height}" ${(poster ? `poster="${poster}` : '')}>`,
   `<source src="${source1}" ${(source1mime ? `type="${source1mime}"` : '')} />`,
   `<source src="${source2}" ${(source2mime ? `type="${source2mime}"` : '')} />`,
   '</video>',
].join(''),
```

Also, please note that all properties should be lowercased.

Comment: Thanks @user2849706